# Search bytecode for calls to System.exit

Tags: java, bytecode, system.exit

I have a Java batch which is mysteriously calling `System.exit`.

Is there a way to statically analyse all bytecode in the classpath to see where calls to `System.exit` could come from?

I don't have access to the environment where the batch is run, so I can't easily modify the environment to trap this call.

Comment: Why do you think that `System.exit` is called? Maybe an exception is thrown which isn't handled and crashes your batch.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but we are getting a return code of 137 in our launcher shell script, and adding the -x parameter to bash shows that the JVM is exiting with a return code of 137.

Comment: If you have an access to application's jar files you can just [decompile](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) it and then search for `System.exit`

Comment: Yes, I know I can decompile, but the batch has about 40 .jars, so something that can search bytecode would be useful :)

Comment: @ Rich : Could you update the question and title to match the discussion. (say java app exit with return code 137 ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found this:

```
If you use Unix/Linux:
Exit-code above 128 means that the process died because of a received
signal (exitCode = 128 + signalNumber).
==> In your case it was signal 9 (= SIGKILL).
```

here: [Understanding error - Java returned: 137](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t136593-understanding-error-java-returned-137-a.html)

So maybe someone `kill`ed your batch.